# Django: Finding part of a view's URL using {% url %}

Tags: django, django-templates, django-urls

I'm having trouble getting only a part of an URL with the `{% url %}` tag.

The URL setup contains this:

```
url("^delete/(?P<uuid>[a-f0-9]{8}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{12})/$",
    deleteView,
    name = "delete"),
```

which means to delete an item by its UUID (the view takes a parameter "uuid" as you can see). As I don't want to change all templates when the URL mappings change, I'm using named URLs ("delete" in this example).

Then in the template, I want to access that URL via AJAX but need to provide the UUID parameter using JavaScript, so really I only need the `/delete/` part of the URL. My current solution is this:

```
uuid = "some uuid that should be deleted on the server";

$.get("{% url myinstancenamespace:delete "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" %}"
      .replace("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000", uuid),
      function(data)
{
    // process server response
}, "text");
```

This seems more like a hack to me. So, are there any better solutions than this?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't sound completely hackish to me, I must say.

But if you really don't want to do it like that, one option would be to make the `uuid` parameter optional in the URLconf, by prefixing it with `?:`. Of course you'd then need to do a bit more validation in the view to ensure that you actually did have a uuid.

Comment: Then I would have to reparse the URL in the view, which leads to another place that must know the URLconf. So that's another (bigger) hack IMO.

Comment: Not at all. The uuid would still be passed in as a parameter, but the function signature would be `def deleteView(request, uuid=None):` and you would just need to check `if uuid is None`.

Comment: Could you please edit your answer to include the full regex, I think I don't get what exactly you mean (doesn't work the way I interpret your answer ;).